# Debug VS Code with Chrome, webRoot property

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am trying to debug a simple node.js project, hitting a break point using Chrome

File structure is simple in C:\node:

node_modules (folder),package.json, server.js

I have installed extension 'Debugger for Chrome' and built a launch.json file

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
          "type": "chrome",
          "request": "launch",
          "name": "Launch Chrome",
          "url":"http://localhost:8080/api",
          "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",   
        }
    ]
}
```

However it does not hit a break point in the server.js file.

I think the issue is the webRoot property.

After a lot of reading and trial and error i ultimately cannot figure this one out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Its not clear, if you want to do client or server side debugging. Have a look at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/debugging-recipes